# Set/Change list properties in application.properties in Akka

Tags: akka, typesafe-config, application.properties

I want to use slf4j for logging, based on [logging doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/logging.html). These config should be changed in `application.conf`:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

I'm using `application.properties` instead of `application.conf`:

```
akka.loggers[0]=akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger
akka.logging-filter=akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter
```

But above config does not change `akka.loggers` value (the value is still the default value: `akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger`).

Printing all configuration:

```
"loggers" : [
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.12/2.5.18/akka-actor_2.12-2.5.18.jar!/reference.conf: 17
    "akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"
],
# application.properties @ file:/home/user/workspace/x-platform/target/test-classes/application.properties
"loggers[0]" : "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger",
# application.properties @ file:/home/user/workspace/x-platform/target/test-classes/application.properties
"logging-filter" : "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter",
```

**So my question is:** how can i set/change value for a list prpperty in `application.properties`?

I'm using akka `2.5.18` with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this the parseString thing?

```
val customConf = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
      akka {
        loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
        logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
      }
      """)
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem", ConfigFactory.load(customConf))
```

or combining custom config with the usual one

```
Config myConfig =ConfigFactory.parseString("loggers=['akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger']");
Config regularConfig = ConfigFactory.load();
Config combined = myConfig.withFallback(regularConfig);
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. the `combined` does not contain other akka related configs which changed in `application.properties` (but it has the correct value for `akka.loggers`)